# Spring Injection - access to the injected object within a constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a resource (Spring bean) which has some of its fields injected by Spring, for example:

```
@Repository(value="appDao")
public class AppDaoImpl implements AppDao {
   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager entityManager;

   public Resource() {
      ... use entityManager ... // doesn't work
   }
}
```

I know that I can't access the injected entityManager in the constructor and should use a `@PostConstruct` annotation on a different method. But what are the reasons for this?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question: the class is AppDaoImpl but you are saying Resource() is contructor? Resource() indeed has constructor syntax but the name is diff.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because Spring can't access any fields or methods before the object is created (which is done through the constructor). So Spring instantiates the object using the constructor and *then* injects the properties.

The only way around this is to use [Constructor Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-ctor) (which can be cumbersome if you have multiple dependencies). I think what you should do is move your code out of the constructor and into an initialization method using [the `@PostConstruct` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations):

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    // do stuff with entitymanager here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason is in the lifecycle of the bean:

- The container (spring application context) instantiates the object
- then it sets all the dependencies (incl. the entityManager in your example)
- after all dependencies have been set, it invokes the `@PostConstruct` method, if any.

Spring (and no one) can set fields to an object before actually constructing that object.

You *can* use constructor-injection - passing the dependencies to a non-default constructor, but it is not possible with `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: It's not possible: `@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD})`